# Meteor JS error; Unexpected token ',' expected '['

Tags: javascript, mongodb, email, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am pretty new at using meteor JS and I have come across this obscure error when trying to supply mongo records to an email template. This was the exct error received

`Errors prevented startup:

While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.osx.x86_64):
server/main.js:22:75: Unexpected token, expected ] (22:75)

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.`

A code snippet is provided to show what my server file looks like.

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
  var smtp = {
    username: 'nayyir.-----@----.com',
    password: '-----------------',
    server: '----.-----.com',
    port: ---
  }
  var vehicle = Mongo.collections('vehicles').findOne();
  var specifications = [];
  var user = Mongo.collections('users').findOne();
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;

  Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function() {
      console.log('on server - sending email');
      SSR.compileTemplate('htmlEmail', Assets.getText('mitsubishi-email.html'));
      for (var i in vehicle['specifications']){
        var spec = Mongo.collections('specattributes').find('_id': vehicle['specifications'][i]['attr_id']);
        var specattributes = {};
        specattributes['spec_value'] = vehicle['specifications'][i].val.en;
        specattributes['spec_category'] = spec;
        specifications.push(specattributes);
      }
      var emailOptions = {
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname,
        specifications = specifications,
        improvements = vehicle.improvements,
        reasons = vehicle.reasonsToBuy
      }

      Email.send({
        to: '------@------.com',
        from: '------@------.com',
        subject: 'Test',
        html: SSR.render('htmlEmail', emailOptions),
      });
      console.log('on server - sent email');
    }
  })
});
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

TIA

Comment: Maybe give us a hint about which line is line 22? You want to make it easy for people to help you. Sure, people could count, but we don't know this is *exactly* your code (maybe you have more or fewer blank lines), and in any case, why make people count?

Comment: Review the [db.collections.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) syntax

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates there's an issue on line 22, which looks like this:

```
var spec = Mongo.collections('specattributes').find('_id': vehicle['specifications'][i]['attr_id']);
```

I think you forgot the curly braces, so it should look like this:

```
var spec = Mongo.collections('specattributes').find({'_id': vehicle['specifications'][i]['attr_id']});
```

Comment: This answer looks correct (and is the correct line), but later in the file there is another place with incorrect syntax. The var emailOptions shouldn't have '=' (assignment) operators when constructing an object.